# How to set OnItemClickListener on custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view that fill with an image and text view in each row, and it shown correct :[[image: [enter image description here]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55dFC.jpg)

but my problem is that I want to show the text that in a Toast in setOnItemClickListener. here is my codes:

```java
public class Showing {
public int icon;
public String title;
public Showing(){
    super();
}

public Showing(int icon, String title) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
}}
```

and my adapter is:

```java
public class ShowingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Showing> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Showing data[] = null;

public ShowingAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Showing[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ShowingHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ShowingHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ShowingHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Showing showing = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(showing.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(showing.icon);

    return row;
}

static class ShowingHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}}
```

And here are my layouts for Header:

```java
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Action Photos"
    android:background="#336699" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And each row

```java
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So here is My Main code :

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Showing action_data[] = new Showing[]
            {
                    new Showing(R.drawable.cut, "Cut"),
                    new Showing(R.drawable.delete, "Delete"),
                    new Showing(R.drawable.favorites, "Favorites"),
                    new Showing(R.drawable.redo, "Redo"),
                    new Showing(R.drawable.up, "Up")
            };

     ShowingAdapter adapter = new ShowingAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, action_data);

    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ***// I want to make a toast here...
            // but the 'VIEW' is LinearLayout and 
            // I want to retrive the 'TEXT VIEW.getText'***
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to act on the layout. You can simply retrieve the object associated with your row. So inside the `onItemClick()` you can get it in this way:

```
Showing showing = (Showing)adapter.getitem(position)
```

now, showing contains all the information you need. So you can get the text:

```
showing.title
```

or if you make title private (as it supposed to be), you would use a getter:

```
showing.getTitle();
```

Comment: wow, you're brilliant... that is works fine. thank you @Joseph82

Comment: You are welcome @Beppe. Consider to accept my answer, if you think that it helped you ;)